# Git & Intellij, How do I commit only parts of a changed file

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-commit

I can't seem to commit only a fraction of the changes in a file, it seems to be all of the file or nothing, I'm using Git with Intellij, is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201

Comment: As pointed out by @mach, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263784/how-to-commit-a-partial-file-hunks-to-git-in-pycharm

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not in the IDE. As noted in comments, you can use the command line, but I find it much easier to use a GUI GIT client (I use [Tower](http://www.git-tower.com/), but there are many available).

Comment: That's a real shame. It's a prominent use case in my git workflow. For now, I use "git add --patch".

Comment: For reference, after using `git add --patch` and selecting the hunks you want, you run `git commit -m XXX` to actually commit it.

Comment: As of 2018, Tower is available in full release for Windows.

Answer (score 51):

**Update - 2/2018:**
The first EAP build for 2018.1 has landed and it's HERE! It is implemented as checkboxes for each hunk, so you can selectively check on them before making the commit. Enjoy!

**Update - 12/2017:**

Well 2017.3 was just released and this didn't make it in. So let's hope for 2018.1.

**Update - 11/2017:**

This has been 'in progress' for months now. The 2017.3 EAP releases have been coming out for a while but this issue hasn't been finished yet. With no updates to the issue other than people asking when it will be done, I'm thinking this will slip to the 2018 release.

**Update - 2017:**

This [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201) has been open for years as noted in some of the comments. But it is now in progress and sheduled to land in 2017.3 which is currently in EAP release and should be available this fall. So now, four years after this was asked, you will soon be able to actually do it right in the IDE.

Comment: so now we just have to wait for it to become true and then for all the great IntelliJ apps to rebase to 2017.3 core :) Can't wait!

Comment: I wanted to come here and add a comment about 2018.1 but you beat me to it :) Anyway, finally `git add -p` in IDEA has come!

Comment: would be nice to somehow never commit `debugger` lines in js

Comment: @Sean yes but we cannot edit an hunk and then commit it. I think we can only either accept or reject a hunk ? So, git add -p will still be needed as such

Comment: Is there a way to remember lines which I selected? It could be a very nice feature

Answer (score 9):

You should try SourceTree(Mac & Windows), It's free and a great tool for working with GIT. It has all the commit freedom you want in a confortable UI.

This is my commit workflow for IntelliJ, from simple to complex task:

1. IntelliJ
2. SourceTree
3. shell GIT.

Answer (score 5):

The wait is finally over, partial commits are part of EAP 18.1: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more/