# How to commit a partial file (hunks) to git in pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm

I'm a heavy Eclipse PyDev + EGit user and looking to switch to PyCharm. In Eclipse, I can choose to add only certain hunks/lines of a file to the git index, the same as using `git add -p` from the terminal. I find doing it through a GUI to be faster, and I have been looking for the same functionality in PyCharm. Does it exist? Thanks

Comment: I don't think those are supported yet in any jetbrains IDE, all are still on file level, if you need to I guess you'll need to go `git add -p` manually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git & Intellij, How do I commit only parts of a changed file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186681/git-intellij-how-do-i-commit-only-parts-of-a-changed-file)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**This is not currently supported.** Follow this ticket for details (comment/watch to be notified when it will be implemented).

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201

---

**UPDATE 2018-03-13:**

This functionality is now implemented ([more or less](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201#comment=27-2715007)) and will be available in **2018.1** version. A bit more can be found [in this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more/).

Comment: @Atcold It's actually work in progress .. but I have no idea if it will get into the next 2017.1 release or not: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201#comment=27-1811752

Comment: That sounds great. For the moment I have to say that [Vim](https://github.com/vim/vim) + [GitGutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) + [Fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) are tools as sharp as a Swiss knife. They let you commit by theme rather by time, meaning **one** commit covers **one** topic, which may have sub tasks, and which are explained in the commit description, below the title. [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) is missing also the colour coding for the commit message. These were just my 2¢.

Comment: @Atcold I answered this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46555732/1046297) but it is now scheduled for release with 2017.3!

Comment: Partial commits [*are* supported](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more/) in the IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 EAP build as of Feb 2018, so presumably will be making it into production releases and the other JetBrains IDEs shortly.

Answer (score 7):

PyCharm manages this through change lists. Here is an example.

1. We create a new change list from an existing one (one that we've already created, or the default changelist).
2. We make a couple of changes and hit `VCS` -> `Commit Changes`
3. In the diagram below at `{1}`, you can see that the changelist is set to `Default`, and in `{2}` you can see the actual change. Right click on `{2}` and select the change.

[image]

Now, say we want to commit *only* this change. We can do this by adding it to a new changelist, by clicking on `{3}`, and this will pop up:

[image]

Since we don't have a new one, let's just create a new changelist using the dialog box. And then let's change the currently selected changelist to `New Changelist`:

[image]

Notice that there is *only* one file, with one change, just like our changelist. How about we add a few things from the `default` changelist to the new one:

[image]

Now, let's head back to the `New Changelist`:

[image]

Now that we're done with our selective changes, press `Commit`. After this, we can push:

[image]

I pushed to bitbucket, so let's see the changes:

[image]

As you can see, only the stuff in the `New Changelist` was added.

Comment: Your example worked for me, but only because `fubar.py` had only one change in it. When I experimented with this further, the `Move to Another Changelist` button only works at the file level; if there were multiple line changes in `fubar.py`, it would have moved every single change to another changelist, not just a single hunk.

Comment: @mach It seems like you're right. I'll try to see if there is a solution to this.

Comment: It's a pity that this didn't actually address the question, because it's a really nice answer

Answer (score 3):

Since *Pycharm 2018* **partial commit** (similar to `git add -p`) can be set up by two settings:

1. Settings-> General -> Other -> **Highlight modified lines in gutter**
   [image]
2. Settings -> Version Control -> Changelists -> **Track changed blocks in text files separately**
   [image]
3. After that, you will be able to move code blocks to different change-lists or de-select blocks from the commit

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a late comment, but may be helpful to some.

1. PyCharm has this [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201) open.  This issue, and its duplicates, has been open since at least 2012.  Don't hold your breath.
2. Putting changes in file by file is trivial, just by clicking boxes.
3. On OS/X, use the GitHub Desktop tool for those cases where you want fine grain commits.   It has the correct 'click and drag over blocks of line' interface for this.

Comment: Hi Robert, StackOverflow users randomly downvote some answers.  In this case, I expect someone disagreed with "Don't hold your breath."  After all, Its only been five years. :)

Comment: Think you're right: but in any case we can release our breath, it's been done: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63201